# AWS cognito: getCredentials not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

Im in the process of learning to use AWS Cognito. I have set up a userpool and a identity pool.

Code (simplified):

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        let cognitoGetUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
        if (cognitoGetUser != null) {
          cognitoGetUser.getSession((err, result) => {
            if (result) {
              console.log ("Authenticated to Cognito User and Identity Pools!");
              let token = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
              let cognitoParams = {
                IdentityPoolId: this.identityPool,
                Logins: {}
              };
              cognitoParams.Logins["cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"+this.poolData.UserPoolId] = token;
              AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams);

              AWS.config.getCredentials(() => {
                  console.log(AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId)
                  console.log(AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey)
                  console.log(AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken)  
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
```

Most of the code works as expected: The `authenticateUser` fires the `onSuccess` and I can see a `jwt` token ect

**Problem:** I cant get the `AWS.config.getCredentials` to work. It executed without any errors, but `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey` and `SessionToken` are all `undefined`.

Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant get the AWS.config.getCredentials to work. **It executed without any errors** but,

This may be a mistaken assumption.  Your abbreviated code is missing a couple of closing parentheses, but ran fine for me without any meaningful adjustments.

---

When calling `getCredentials`, any errors are "silently" reported through an `error` object.  I would think you'd see a `400` response somewhere (network tab or console or both), but `getCredentials()` doesn't really report errors in a visible fashion by itself.

To see what is going wrong, you should add a parameter to the callback you pass to `getCredentials()`:

```
AWS.config.getCredentials((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId)
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey)
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken)
    }
});
```

---

For reference, one commonly encountered error object looks like this.  Note that the *useful* message is found in `originalError.message`:

```
{
    "message": "Could not load credentials from CognitoIdentityCredentials",
    "code": "CredentialsError",
    "time": "2018-06-03T15:19:02.078Z",
    "requestId": "71b03b4a-6741-11e8-98af-b70a114474f8",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 94.28032122526344,
    "originalError": {
        "message": "Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName",
        "code": "NotAuthorizedException",
        "time": "2018-06-03T15:19:02.078Z",
        "requestId": "71b03b4a-6741-11e8-98af-b70a114474f8",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 94.28032122526344
    }
}
```

The corresponding `400` in the Network tab contains this response:

```
{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName"}
```